# Where was the Mary Celeste wrecked?

Tags: ships, caribbean

Where exactly (coordinates) was the Mary Celeste shipwrecked (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Celeste):

> On January 3, 1885, Mary Celeste approached the port via the channel between Gonâve Island and the mainland, in which lay a large and well-charted coral reef, the Rochelois Bank. Parker deliberately ran the ship on to this reef, ripping out her bottom and wrecking her beyond repair.

See my map of major U.S. maritime disasters [here](https://ramblingnotesofageezer.substack.com/p/how-to-use-map-o-matic-7-in-a-series).

Comment: The text seems to imply that the captain in question used a rocky feature somewhere along the shoreline to wreck the ship. Given that, what would an acceptible answer to this question look like? The name of the nearest port? GPS coordinates?

Comment: Are you confident that there is an answer to this question? [Smithsonian](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/abandoned-ship-the-mary-celeste-174488104/) implies that the best we can achieve is an estimate.

Comment: I've edited the question with text from the more detailed meat of the linked WP entry, rather than just the blurb up at the top. I take it from previous edits this still isn't enough to answer the question? It seems pretty nailed-down to me.

Comment: @MCW: Estimate is good enough; something better than my guesstimate of 19.989571, -73.625557

Comment: @T.E.D.: Coordinates, as I think I mention in the question

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I think you might be looking at the wrong channel? That position is between Haiti and Cuba - the Rochelois reef is about 18.63, -73.20, closer to Port-au-Prince. I don't think we'd be able to get any more precise unless a contemporary source happens to mention eg the north or south side of the bank.